# Sharing PCIe virtual functions available on the host with a docker container

Tags: docker, containers, atomic

My host is running in SRIOV mode and has several physical devices that appear on the PCIe bus.  Each physical function has a collection of 32 virtual functions.  I want to share one of the virtual function with a docker container.  These are crypto/compression accelerators, and I wrote a driver for one; so I'm familiar with SRIOV when I'm dealing with bare-metal or SRIOV hypervisors launching virtual machines.  But now I'm trying to get access to the virtual functions inside a docker container.

On the host I can lspci and see my physical and virtual devices.  But when I launch a container, all I see from within the container are the physical functions.

I have seen the "--device" parameter for "docker run", but I don't think it will work for passing a virtual function to a container.

Logistically, here's what I see on the host:

```
[localhost] config # lspci | grep "^85" | head -4
85:00.0 Co-processor: Intel Corporation DH895XCC Series QAT
85:01.0 Co-processor: Intel Corporation DH895XCC Series QAT Virtual Function
85:01.1 Co-processor: Intel Corporation DH895XCC Series QAT Virtual Function
85:01.2 Co-processor: Intel Corporation DH895XCC Series QAT Virtual Function
[localhost] config # lspci | grep "^85" | wc
     33     295    2524
```

So we have 1 physical function at 85:00.0, and 32 virtuals.

But when I start the container and do the same examination from inside the container, all I see is the following:

```
[localhost] config # lspci | grep QAT
04:00.0 Co-processor: Intel Corporation DH895XCC Series QAT
05:00.0 Co-processor: Intel Corporation DH895XCC Series QAT
85:00.0 Co-processor: Intel Corporation DH895XCC Series QAT
```

I've been told that this can be made to work:  I can send in virtuals into the container, and my driver can do the rest.

My question:  how can I pass virtual functions from the host into a container?

Comment: Docker allows you to alter the available capabilities for the given container. This is part of some simple cgroup security measures to prevent exposing too much of the host system to the containers. What you probably want is `--cap-add` with some attribute from https://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities . Of course if you don't care much about security considerations (careful, here be dragons) you can always run with `--privileged`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment (but with the flag name):

```
docker run -it --rm --cap-add=SYS_RAWIO ...
```

Then try lspci from inside the container again.